# C# On failling validating cell's value, turns cell to its previous correct value

Tags: datagridview, cell

I would like to cell turns into its previous correct value after validating fails. I have used:

```
DataGridView.CancelEdit()
```

but sometimes works and sometimes not so I force cell's value to take its correct previous value by assigning it to the cell. The problem is that cellvaluechanged event is raised and in this case, I do not want it to be raised.

What is the best way to turns cell's value into its previous correct one if cancelEdit does not work? And If the only way is by forcing it as I have done, how to avoid cellvaluechanged to be raised?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling dataGridView.EndEdit() after dataGridView.CancelEdit()..